# Linux- passwordless ssh from system (root) script

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

What's the easiest way to have a system script (running as root) execute remote commands over ssh?

I've written some scripts that execute commands remotely via ssh, and they work great when I run them as myself, as I've set up ssh-agent and keys for passwordless login.  I'd like to call these when my laptop docks and undocks.  I've been successful at running arbitrary scripts when docking/undocking, but since the ACPI event scripts run as root, trying to run my ssh script fails during authentication.

I tried using sudo with the -u and -i flags to simulate running the script as my user, e.g.:

```
sudo -u redmoskito -i /home/redmoskito/bin/remote_command
```

which successfully finds my private key and tries to use it, but the ssh-agent credentials are still missing, so it still needs my passphrase.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH: execute sudo command](http://superuser.com/questions/117870/ssh-execute-sudo-command)

Comment: @Sathya The user in that post is trying to execute a remote command as root on the server, whereas I'm trying to execute a remote command as root on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the sudo part. To pick up an existing ssh agent, see these answers: [Sharing the same `ssh-agent` among multiple login sessions](https://superuser.com/questions/141044/sharing-the-same-ssh-agent-among-multiple-login-sessions)