# Use sudo command for script SSH server

Tags: linux, script, sudo, su

I have to do following steps on several servers:

1. log in with my username
2. type in `sudo su -`
3. type in `amCLI -l 32/1 | grep Firmware`

So I would like to write this all in one script, my idea was:

```
#!bin/bash
for hostname in DPM-BZ0201 DPM-BZ0202
do
ssh -n vneudeck@$hostname "sudo su-; amCLI -l 32/1 | grep Firmware"
done
```

or

```
#!bin/bash
for hostname in DPM-BZ0201 DPM-BZ0202
do
ssh -n vneudeck@$hostname "sudo amCLI -l 32/1 | grep Firmware"
done
```

Both don't work though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH: execute sudo command](http://superuser.com/questions/117870/ssh-execute-sudo-command)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to set up sudo so that your user is allowed to execute `/full/path/to/amCLI` without providing a password.

Then you can simply

```
#!bin/bash
for hostname in DPM-BZ0201 DPM-BZ0202
do
    ssh -n vneudeck@$hostname sudo /full/path/to/amCLI -l 32/1 | grep Firmware
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put vneudeck@$hostname in double quotation, it will help.
And there is no space between su and -
I hope it is helpfull

Comment: The double quotes are not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

The first one won't work:

```
sudo su -; amCLI -l 32/1 | grep Firmware
```

This would execute `sudo su -`, and when this returned (i.e. when you were done processing commands as root and exited) it would execute amCLI. (Note also that an alternative to `sudo su` is `sudo -s`, though `sudo su -` does more I think.)

The second version might work with some conditions: `sudo` should not be asking for a password, and `amCLI` should be in PATH (not root's path, which is probably set when you type `sudo su -`, but your path, because sudo uses your path). Try specifying the full path to `amCLI`, such as `/usr/local/sbin/amCLI` or whatever it is.

Comment: For security reasons, you should *always* give full path when running things under `sudo` script-driven. Otherwise, anyone capable of putting a file named `amCli` somewhere into the PATH of user `vneudeck` (which might be comparatively easy) has access to root priviledges.